# How do you take a suffix of a string in bash using negative offsets?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to take the suffix of a string in Bash using the `${string:pos}` substring syntax, but I cannot figure out why it won't work. I have managed to simplify my example code to this:

```
STRING="hello world"

POS=4
echo ${STRING:POS} # prints "o world"
echo ${STRING:4}   # prints "o world"

POS=-4
echo ${STRING:POS} # prints "orld"
echo ${STRING:-4}  # prints "hello world"
```

The first three lines work exactly as I would expect, but why does the final line print `"hello world"` instead of `"orld"`?

Answer (score 21):

Because `:-` is parameter expansion syntax to "Use default values".

From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

> When not performing substring expansion, using the form described
>   below (e.g., ‘:-’), Bash tests for a parameter that is unset or
>   null.

So by doing `${STRING:-4}` you are actually asking bash to expand
`STRING` and if it is unset (have never been assigned before) or null
(a null string, printed as `''`) it will substitute the expansion with
`4`. In your example, `STRING` is set and thus it is expanded to its value.

As another answer states, you need to scape the expression to not
trigger the default value behavior, the manual specifies it:

> Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at
>   least one space to avoid being confused with the :- expansion.

For example:

```bash
${STRING:(-4)}
${STRING: -4}
```

Comment: Well, that's delightfully ambiguous.

Answer (score 9):

You need to "escape" parameters starting with dash with a parenthesis or a space, otherwise bash will treat it as a normal string:

```
echo ${STRING:(-4)}
echo ${STRING: -4}
```